# C program to calculates the number of ways to choose k objects from n distinct objects. 'k' and 'n' both are integers

Tags: c, algorithm, function, combinations, coredump

I wrote a C program to calculate the number of ways to choose k objects from n distinct objects using functions.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    long f(int a)
    {
     if(a==1||a==0)return(0);
     else return(a*f(a-1));
    }

    int combination(int N,int K)
    {
     long int NF,KF,NMKF;
     NF=f(N);
     KF=f(K);
     NMKF=f(N-K);
     return(NF/(KF*NMKF));

    }
    int main()
    {
     int n,k;
     scanf("%d%d",&n,&k);
     combination(n,k);
    }
```

But the compiler shows following error message

```
floating point exception (core dumped)
```

How to avoid it?

Comment: Calculating binomial coefficients from factorials is a very bad idea.

Comment: The error looks like an arithmetical error (division by zero, modulo by zero, etc...)

Comment: You could have found out this by your own. You should learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: the COMPILER cannot show the exception. (unless in strangest circumstances when the compiler crashes by itself)

Answer (score 12):

The problem is in this line

```
if(a==1||a==0)return(0);
```

It should be

```
if(a==1||a==0)return(1);
```

While calculating factorial, `n*(n-1)*(n-2)...*(2)*(1)`. Notice in the end, we multiply by `1` and not zero. multiplying with `0` would make the factorial `0`. And later when you are performing division, the `0` comes in the denominator, and `floating point exception` is occurring. That's why your program is giving error.

For cases when factorial of `0` is needed. Then also this would work, because factorial of `0` is 1 and **not** `0`.. Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mfk_L4Nx2ZI) out.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

1. `if(a==1||a==0)` you should `return 1`, not `return 0`. Because `1!=1, 0!=1`.
2. Your intention is `choose k objects from n distinct objects`. But You should add param checking in order to not occur the `n<k`. If we input `n=2, k=3`.The program will go to error. It is bad!
   I hope this can help you.

Comment: Good, second point was not explained in the highest upvoted answer, +1.